# Finding items that meet a condition

Tags: prolog

I have a database similar to:

```
item(coin, [gold, metal, round]).
....
item(ball, [sphere, bouncy, -red]).  % notice the negated property
```

My goal is to find the items that match a given property.

An example of what the problem is:

```
?- findall(I, (item(I, P), properties_true(P, [gold], [], match)), Items).
Items = [coin, ball]
```

`findall/3` is returning ALL items.  The goal, in this instance, was to retrieve only the gold items.

I suspect it's because `item/2` is actually returning all items and hence adding it to Items.  My assumption was that `properties_true/4` would be false for `ball` and therefore it wouldn't get added to `Items`.

Is someone able to point me in the right direction?

Below are the rules I'm using:

```
%% properties_true(Prop, True, False, SearchType)
%
%  Prop = the items to search
%  True = List of properties that must be in Prop
%  False = List of items that mustn't be in Prop
%  SearchType = match|solve
%    * solve = Return true if item has all of True and none of False
%    * match = Return true if item has 0 or more of true and none of False  
% 
% 
properties_true([-Property|Rest], True, False, SearchType) :-
    !, property_true(-Property, True, False, SearchType),
    properties_true(Rest, True, [Property|False], SearchType), !.
properties_true([Property|Rest], True, False, SearchType) :-
    property_true(Property, True, False, SearchType),
    properties_true(Rest, [Property|True], False, SearchType), !.

%% property_true/4
%
properties_true([], _, _, _) :- !.
property_true(-Property, _, False, solve) :-
    !, member(Property, False).
property_true(-Property, True, _, match) :-
    !, not(member(Property, True)).
property_true(Property, True, _, solve) :-
    !, member(Property, True).
property_true(Property, _, False, _) :-
    !, not(member(Property, False)).
property_true(_ , [], [], solve) :- !. % dont think i really need this
```

Example usage:

```
?- properties_true([sphere, bouncy, -red], [], [], match).
true.

?- properties_true([sphere, bouncy, -red], [], [], solve). % solve needs to match all     properties
false.

?- properties_true([sphere, bouncy, -red], [sphere, bouncy], [red], solve).
true.
```

Comment: In comments you have : * match = Return true if item has 0 or more of true and none of False . Well in the query "findall(I, (item(I, P), properties_true(P, [gold], [], match)), Items)." you search for property [gold] in the item ball which has 0 "golds" so it should be true? Perhaps match should return true if it has 1 or more?

Comment: @ssBarBee Good eye!  I've been doing some more testing after writing the question and came to the conclusion that I had a logic error exactly for that reason.  My assumptions were wrong from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a suggestion: normalize your data. Instead of:

```
item(coin, [gold,metal,round]).
item(ball, [sphere, bouncy, -red]).
```

say:

```
item(coin).
item(ball).
item(chair).
item(keyboard).

item_property(coin, gold).
item_property(coin, metal).
item_property(coin, red).
item_property(ball, sphere).
item_property(ball, bouncy).
item_property(ball, -red).
item_property(chair, black).
item_property(chair, -bouncy).
item_property(keyboard, black).
item_property(keyboard, plastic).
```

It is now much easier to write a `match_property/2` predicate:

```
match_property(Property, Item) :-
    (   Property = -NegP
    ->  match_neg_property(NegP, Item)
    ;   item_property(Item, Property)
    ).

match_neg_property(NegP, Item) :-
    item(Item),
    once(neg_property(Item, NegP)).

neg_property(Item, NegP) :-
    item_property(Item, -NegP).
% whether you actually want this clause depends on how you model your world!
neg_property(Item, NegP) :-
    \+ item_property(Item, NegP).

match_property_list(PList, Item) :-
    foreach(
        member(P, PList),
        match_property(P, Item)
    ).
```

Please note how you don't necessarily need to have two "modes" for positive and negative properties. I am not sure how this fits in your general idea (Prolog says "if it's not true it must be false"; having negative properties explicit is not the same, but your initial code suggests you still want to have "negation as failure").

But with these basic building blocks, you can now easily say:

```
?- match_property(-red, Item).
Item = ball ;
Item = chair ;
Item = keyboard.

?- match_property_list([-red, -plastic], Item).
Item = ball ;
Item = chair ;
false.

?- match_property_list([black, -bouncy], Item).
Item = chair ;
Item = keyboard.
```

I am not sure if this answers your question but it seems a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  I decided not to normalise the data as the database shown here is a simplification.  Ie. each property can also be a category which can hold a list of properties.  As I only started using prolog last Thursday I couldn't wrap my head around all the nested -categorys and -properties.  But after your solution I think ill give it another shot.  As per the different modes of search; a partial match:any item that has all of the given properties and none of the negated ones.  A complete match:  itema properties must match all given properties (including negated items).

Comment: @Bosis Thanks for the answer.  It has held and has pointed me in a better direction. :)

Comment: @br3nt Ok, I didn't read the question carefully enough... It should be doable with some additions. Anyway, please consider normalizing the data even if it looks clumsy. Writing queries on it is going to be much easier!

Comment: I just remembered another reason I didn't normalise the data.  My thinking was that searching all the data each time a property was added would be time consuming compared to just selecting all items first and removing items that didn't match.  Ie. one property is added at a time to narrow the choice down to a final item(s).  I suppose its a question of time complexity vs space complexity.  Im not sure if this is a big consideration when using prolog or not.  Either way, in this case, your solution holds and normalising the data is the way to go.

Comment: @br3nt This is a bigger topic, but briefly, I am not convinced that your time vs. space assumptions hold. Facts should not take more space, necessarily (and in a normalized database you would also avoid duplication). Lookup of facts is also very efficient. And if your data changes very often you should use a proper data structure anyway (so a map / hash table, not a list).